# Ionic Fcm background push notification with badge in app icon not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using Ionic FCM push plugin but android badge icon on app is not working its working on IPHONE

Everything is working except badge in android

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/

Please suggestions